# Customising force-directed graph layout

Tags: graph-theory, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I would like to implement a variant of the force-directed graph layout where some nodes are constrained to moving only along a predefined curve (e. g. circle).  I looked at some implementations using the Gauss-Seidel method and roughly followed what's going on but I was wondering if there's a standard way to solve this kind of problem?

PS. I would like the layout to be animated and (ideally) interactive.